# how to use Oracle's dbms crypto to create htpasswd compatible passwords

Tags: oracle, plsql, .htpasswd, dbms-crypto

Is there any way to use Oracles DBMS_CRYPTO PL/SQL package to create passwords
that are compatible with apache's htpasswd?  So in a PL/SQL package I create a hashed password which when later stored in an .htpasswd file, will work fine.

We currently do this in unix with the command htpasswd -n -b -d.  However, we would like to create them and save them in an Oracle table.  Then retrieve them to create the .htpasswd files when needed.

Thanks!

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `htpasswd` tool is capable of generating a handful of hashed password types.  You're using the `-d` flag, which uses the prehistoric `crypt()` hash format.  `crypt()` hashes are amazingly insecure and deliciously easy to crack.

According to [this manual page from Oracle 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm), the `DBMS_CRYPTO` package *does not* support `crypt()`.  This isn't surprising.

You're going to need to switch to a different hashing algorithm in order to pull this off.  The most straight-forward way would be the equivalent of using the `-s` flag instead of the `-d` flag to create SHA1 passwords.  Try it out on the command line to see the results.  The password format given is the literal string `{SHA}`, followed by the base64 encoded SHA1 hash, with no salting.  The `DBMS_CRYPTO` package seems to support SHA1 and hints that there's a function to do base64 encoding as well.  Or, if you're doing the .htpasswd file generation yourself, you can simply store the hash in whatever way you prefer and convert it on output using your language of choice.

Comment: Charles;Thanks very much for the informative reply.  I apologize for my late response but have been away for a few days.  I'll give this a try and post my results.